# How to move a border bottom so it starts past the text?

Tags: html, css

I know I can move my border bottom up and down via padding or line height, but how do I move it left and right so that the beginning of the border begins after the text starts, like

TEXTTEXTEXT

```
      ______________
```

Thank you

Current Code:

```
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

h1 {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

This extends the length of the border to the right, but it doesn't change its beginning point, so it looks like

TEXTTEXTEXT

```
___________________
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show? By the way, you can move it left and right with padding as well.

Comment: Currently I have a div named title, with my text in an h1 tag, I'll put the styling in the original post cause this comment formatting is messing with me

Comment: try messing with the margin and padding

Comment: [This article](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_margin-left) might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an **:after** pseudo-class, then you can add a DOM element after the title that can be absolutely positioned the way you want it.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>TEXTTEXTEXT</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using text indent like this. Not a good idea. But solves problem

```
border-bottom:5px solid #ccc;
margin-left:50px;
text-indent:-40px;
```

Comment: There may be a better idea than that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `box-shadow`, but the background has to be a solid color you can match.

```css
p {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 50px 0px 0px 0px white, 50px 2px 0px 0px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Underlined Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that great but you could do something like this:

```
    <div>
     <h1>TEXT HERE</<h1>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    div {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    }

    h1 {
      position: relative;
      left: -30px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
     }
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRPNVZ